# Finding the Hessian of $\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)))+\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I had a previous question, but I changed the whole question, so I'm going to change that back to its original question, and write my new question here:

How to find the Hessian matrix of the function $$f(\beta_0,\beta_1)=\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)))+\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)))$$?

I think I have to find the $x_1$ second partial and $x_2$ second partial and the mixed second partial $\frac{\partial f^2}{x_1x_2}$. Then the Hessian is Hermitian, so it is symmetric too (I think) to get the other entry (which I guess would be the other mixed partial.

I am having trouble calculating the partial derivatives.

Comment: Technically, I'm trying to show something from my other question. I'm trying to find whether or not I have convexity, which I can show if I can find out if the Hessian's determinant is greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

You wrote derivatives w.r.t to $x_1, x_2$, but you have $f$ as a function of $\beta _0 , \beta _1$. I'm assuming that is not a mistake, otherwise my partials are completely wrong.

$\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial \beta _0 ^2} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta _0}([\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)}} * e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)} *-y_1] + [\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}}*e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}*-y_2 ] \\ =
\frac{[(1+e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)})*-y_1 e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)}*-y_1] - [(e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)} *-y_1) *e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)}*-y_1]}{(1+e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)})^2} + \frac{[(1+e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)})*-y_2 e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}*-y_2)-[(e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}*-y_2)*(-y_2*e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)})]}{(1+e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)})^2} \\
= \frac{y_1^2 *e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)}}{(1+e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)})} -\frac{y_1^2 *e^{-2 y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)}}{(1+e^{-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)})^2} +\frac{y_2^2 e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}}{1+e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}} -\frac{y_2^2 e^{-2y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)}}{1+e^{-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)})^2}$

Assuming I have made no mistakes, that has to be positive because all the terms we are subtracting are larger than what we are adding (the negative terms have larger denominators).

Do this for $\beta_1$ and the mixed case, similarly find why they are positive (If memory serves), or if you want to show the determinant is greater than 0 find a reason for that, and there you go.

If you have questions on the derivative, feel free to ask, but I am not taking the other derivatives for you.